# How can I know whether a notification icon is displayed?

Tags: android

I know I can use the function `displayNotifyIcon` to display a notification icon

1. How can I know whether a notification icon is displayed programmatically?
2. What happened after I invoke the `displayNotifyIcon` if the notification icon is already displayed?

**Code**

```
fun displayNotifyIcon(mContext: Context, myIntent:Intent, isServer: Boolean=false) {
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

    val pendingIntent =if (isServer) {
        PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }  else {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }

    val notificationManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager


    var builder = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(mContext.getString(R.string.NotificationChannelID),
                mContext.getString(R.string.NotificationChannelName),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, notificationChannel.id)
    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
    }

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallnotify)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.resources, R.drawable.largernotify))
            .setContentTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.NotificationTitle))
            .setTicker(mContext.getString(R.string.NotificationTitle))
            .setContentText( mContext.getString(R.string.NotificationContent))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val notification = builder.build()
    notification.flags = notification.flags or NotificationCompat.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT 
    notification.flags = notification.flags or NotificationCompat.FLAG_NO_CLEAR 

    notificationManager.notify(mContext.resources.getInteger(R.integer.NotificationID), notification)
}


fun clearNotifyIcon(mContext: Context) {
    val notificationManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.cancel(mContext.resources.getInteger(R.integer.NotificationID))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What happened after I invoke the displayNotifyIcon if the notification icon is already displayed

notificationManager.notify(mContext.resources.getInteger(R.integer.NotificationID), notification)

Here, you have used a fixed integer value mContext.resources.getInteger(R.integer.NotificationID), so it'll override the existing notification, and only the latest notification will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks! How can I know whether a notification icon is displayed programmatically?